# Access a custom C# Dictionary Iterator in Scriban

Tags: c#, iterator, scriban

I got a `Dictionary<string, object>` where I want to format the object on the fly. This works in the console, the problem is that I need to access those values in my Scriban template.

That's how I implemented my custom Iterator:

```
public class Workflow {
    public Dictionary<string, object>? Variables { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<(string key, string value)> GetVariables() {
        foreach (var kvp in Variables) {
            yield return (kvp.Key, FormatUtils.FormatVariable(kvp.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I pass it to my renderer:

```
template.Render(new {
     variables = workflow.GetVariables()
});
```

And then I want to access my keys and values in my scriban template:

```
{{~ for var in variables ~}}
  {{ var.key }}: {{ var.value }} 
{{~ end ~}}
```

This worked when I accessed `Variables` directly. Now I just got no outputs, as `key` and `value` is not defined (this is the output for `variables` in Scriban):

```
[(JOB_NUMBER, 42), (JOB_DESC, "New Car")]
```

It looked like this with `Variables` passed instead:

```
[{key: "JOB_NUMBER", value: 42}, {key: "JOB_DESC", value: "New Car"}]
```

How do I fix the access to my values?

Comment: The named tuple syntax doesn't define new fields, it's only syntactic sugar. The actual fields are still `Item1`, `Item2` etc. Either create a `record` with the names you want or return a `KeyValuePair<string,string>`. You could replace the entire method with `Variables.Select(pair=>new KeyValuePair(pair.Key,FormatUtils.FormatVariable(kvp.Value))`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, that was an easy one... If you post this as answer, I can accept it.